# How to fix length of hashed value in passlib context python?

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, passlib

I am using below code for encrypting password.

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext

pwd_context = CryptContext(
    schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
    default="pbkdf2_sha256",
    pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=30000
 )

 def encrypt_password(password):
    return pwd_context.encrypt(password)


 def check_encrypted_password(password, hashed):
    return pwd_context.verify(password, hashed)
```

When I call `encrypt_password('password')` function it will encrypt my password into hash value and give me output as follow..

```
'$pbkdf2-sha256$30000$X6vVGgNgzFmrlVIq5RyjVA$VGQ5x.yuabpdNMDMNc1S3/umqXMl3605DyjJ/lgXAM0'
```

The output of encypted password hashed value is too long value. I want to get output in fixed sized like "30 characters or 40 characters". How to get fix sized output.? Can anyone help me to understand this.

Thank You !

Comment: Why do you want or expect that output length?

Comment: For storing it on database. But It's Okay I did R & D and Understand that we can't reduce hash characters into some length because it's automatically generated. Solved my problem.